# Binding a name for JavaScript function using variable name

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function, extends

I'm having an issue with the following:

[image]

I think the issue is clear, the anonymous function does not take the name of its variable .

Therefore, how do I extend `Function Object` Constructor to give a name to a function according to the affected variable?

Comment: Why don't you just use `function i_am` instead of `var i_am = function`?

Comment: I don't think that's possible

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
var i_am = function i_am() { return "I Sure Am!"; }
```

That syntax has always been valid, but in the past there have been [some browser quirks about that](https://kangax.github.io/nfe/).  If those quirks are of concern, you can always do this:

```
function i_am() {
  return "I Sure Am!";
}

var i_am = i_am;
```

That's a *little* bit fishy, because the binding for "i_am" in the local scope is highjacked from the function, but the function retains the *internal* binding of the name.

Now, there's no way to retroactively give a function an internally-bound name. Functions are pretty much frozen upon creation (and if you think about language semantics and optimization, that's the way it should be).

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The name of the function is determined as you create the function.

If you use an unnamed function expression, then the function will be created (with no name) and *then* assigned to the variable.

Since the variable doesn't come anywhere near the function before then, it can't be used to determine the function's name.

If you want to give a function created with a function expression a name, then use a named function expression.

```
var addFn = function addFn () {};
```

(Warning: Old versions of Internet Explorer have memory leak and scope related bugs surrounding named function expressions).